# C# error "Could not find Stored procedure" if DB collation is not “SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS”

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

This is the situation that I encountered:

---

**A) C# code: execute stored procedure "Check_Data"**

- I would like to state that there is nothing wrong with my C# code here as it is as basic as it can get, and it is also double-checked by me and my co-workers.

**B) SQL Server:**

- All DBs are MSSQL2005. Please do not suggest to upgrade them, as this is what my client uses.
- Please note that all 4 DBs below is created in the exact same way, as well as the stored procedure "Check_Data". The only difference is the collation of each DB.
- I used user "sa" to connect to all DB to make sure that there is no problem with permission.
- **Instance A:** collation “SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS”

  - **DB 1:** collation “SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS”
    => C# code run successful.
  - **DB 2:** collation “Vietnamese_CI_AS”
    => C# code has error "Could not find Stored procedure" .
- **Instance B:** collation “Vietnamese_CI_AS”

  - **DB 1:** collation “SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS”
    => C# code run successful.
  - **DB 2:** collation “Vietnamese_CI_AS”

> => C# code has error "Could not find Stored procedure" .

---

So basically, my DB just hate collation `“Vietnamese_CI_AS”` and refuse to get this stored procedure.

This is the script of **"Check_Data"**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Check_Data]
(   
    @Acc    nvarchar(50),   
    @Status varchar(500) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN

if exists (select 1 from tblRequest where Acc=@Acc)

    SET @Status = '1'--have data
else
    SET @Status = '0'--have not data        
END
```

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with it?

**UPDATE**

When I use above script to create new proc will different name (Check_Acc), the code call this new proc successfully.

Therefore, for the time being, I will go with this solution and rename all proc that have this problem.

However, I am really appreciated if I know what make the code unable to call the original proc.

Comment: I would expect a different error message... What happens when you run the SQL outside of the stored proc?
Changing the collation on the database only changes the defaults for new objects and new calls. I suspect you may need to either drop and re-create the proc, or specify the collation in the where clause

Comment: I have tried drop and re-create it, but the error still occur.
However, it I create a new one with the same script, only change the name of the proc, then it is OK.
Now I am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this Forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/914cf3a4-3151-4e5f-8c88-68a8ec8d3b4f/stored-procedure-could-not-find?forum=sqlsearch). Try to Change your CommandText to

```
execute stored procedure "Check_Data"
```

or create a proper SqlCommand with Type StoredProcedure

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Check_Data",yourConn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: As I said in my post, I do not think the C# code is at fault, as when I change the connection to another DB with collation “SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS”, everything is fine. This error only show when the collation of DB is “Vietnamese_CI_AS”.